# sed join lines together

Tags: regex, linux, sed

what would be the sed (or other tool) command to join lines together in a file that do not end w/ the character '0'?

I'll have lines like this

> ```
> 412|n|Leader Building Material||||||||||d|d|20||0
> ```

which need to be left alone, and then I'll have lines like this for example (which is 3 lines, but only one ends w/ 0)

> ```
> 107|n|Knot Tying Tools|||||Knot Tying Tools
>
> |||||d|d|0||0
> ```

which need to be joined/combined into one line

> ```
> 107|n|Knot Tying Tools|||||Knot Tying Tools|||||d|d|0||0
> ```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
 sed ':a;/0$/{N;s/\n//;ba}'
```

In a loop (branch `ba` to label `:a`), if the current line ends in 0 (`/0$/`) append next line (`N`) and remove inner newline (`s/\n//`).

**awk:**

```
awk '{while(/0$/) { getline a; $0=$0 a; sub(/\n/,_) }; print}'
```

**Perl:**

```
perl -pe '$_.=<>,s/\n// while /0$/'
```

**bash:**

```
while read line; do 
    if [ ${line: -1:1} != "0" ] ; then 
        echo $line
    else echo -n $line
fi
done
```

Comment: question says join if line does `NOT` end with '0'. Given sed does the opposite.

Comment: Here is the one that solves the problem OP asked for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094997/merge-lines-between-two-patterns-using-sed

Comment: The bash loop, even though it looks uglier, it's actually quite a bit faster, more flexible and easier to understand and debug. I was able to adapt it to join lines where the criteria was: join each line starting with "https": with all the following lines until the next one that starts with "https:".

Comment: On macOS, the branching didn't work for me, but removing it did: `sed '/my pattern/{N;s/\n//;}'`

Answer (score 10):

awk could be short too:

```
awk '!/0$/{printf $0}/0$/'
```

test:

```
kent$  cat t
#aasdfasdf
#asbbb0
#asf
#asdf0
#xxxxxx
#bar

kent$  awk '!/0$/{printf $0}/0$/' t
#aasdfasdf#asbbb0
#asf#asdf0
#xxxxxx#bar
```

Comment: Hi! Could you add a short description on how this works please? :)

Comment: it is very straightforward which part you have problem to understand?

Comment: Well: (1) What command is that, with four slashes? (2) How does that last "0$" part work? (3) Generally, how to search for documentation for this command

Comment: Having played around with this for almost an hour now, can you confirm the following explanation: For every line which does not have 0 at the end, print that line (without newline). Then, another regex begins: For every line which _has_ a 0 at the end, don't touch it (which result in "print it normally, including it's newline")

Answer (score 4):

The rating of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7853846) is surprising `;s` (this surprised wink emoticon pun on sed substitution is intentional) given the OP specifications: [sed join lines together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852132/sed-join-lines-together).

This [submission's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7852201)  last comment

> "if that's the case check what @ninjalj submitted"

also suggests checking the [same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7853846).

ie.  Check using `sed ':a;/0$/{N;s/\n//;ba}'` verbatim

```
sed ':a;/0$/{N;s/\n//;ba}'
 does
 no one
 ie. 0
 people,
 try
 nothing,

 ie. 0
 things,
 any more,
 ie. 0
 tests?

          (^D aka eot 004 ctrl-D ␄  ... bash generate via: echo ^V^D)
```

which will not give (do the test ;):

```
 does no one ie. 0
 people, try nothing, ie. 0
 things, any more, ie. 0
 tests?          (^D aka eot 004 ctrl-D ␄  ... bash generate via: echo ^V^D)
```

To get this use:

```
sed 'H;${z;x;s/\n//g;p;};/0$/!d;z;x;s/\n//g;'
```

or:

```
sed ':a;/0$/!{N;s/\n//;ba}'
```

not:

```
sed ':a;/0$/{N;s/\n//;ba}'
```

---

Notes:

```
sed 'H;${x;s/\n//g;p;};/0$/!d;z;x;s/\n//g;'
```

does not use branching and
is identical to:

```
sed '${H;z;x;s/\n//g;p;};/0$/!{H;d;};/0$/{H;z;x;s/\n//g;}'
```

- `H` commences all sequences
- `d` short circuits further script command execution on the current line and starts the next cycle so address selectors following `/0$/!` can only be `/0$/!!` so the address selector of
  `/0$/{H;z;x;s/\n//g;}` is redundant and not needed.
- if a line does not end with 0 save it in hold space
  `/0$/!{H;d;}`
- if a line does end with 0 save it too and then print flush (double entendre ie. purged and lines aligned)
  `/0$/{H;z;x;s/\n//g;}`
- NB `${H;z;x;s/\n//g;p;}` uses `/0$/ ...` commands with an extra `p` to coerce the final print and with a now unnecessary `z` (to empty and reset pattern space like s/.*//)

Answer (score 3):

A typically cryptic Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{$/="0\n"}s/\n//g;$_.=$/'
```

This uses the sequence "0\n" as the record separator (by your question, I'm assuming that every line should end with a zero). Any record then should not have internal newlines, so those are removed, then print the line, appending the 0 and newline that were removed.

Another take to your question would be to ensure each line has 17 pipe-separated fields. This does not assume that the 17th field value must be zero.

```
awk -F \| '
    NF == 17 {print; next}
    prev {print prev $0; prev = ""}
    {prev = $0}
'
```

Answer (score 2):

if ends with 0 store, remove newline..

```
sed '/0$/!N;s/\n//'
```

Comment: I don't think this quite works. If I understand the question, a compete lack of zeros should give one big line. But when I try `$ ls | sed '/0$/!N;s/\n//' I find that it only joins lines in pairs.

Comment: Eric, you are correct.  if there is NO 0 then I need to remove the newline

Comment: if that's the case check what @ninjalj submitted.