# Merge lines between two patterns using sed

Tags: sed, grep

I have an output file that looks like this:

```
HEADER 1:
server1 server2 server3
server4 server5 server6
server7 server8 server9
HEADER 2:

HEADER 1:
server10 server11 server12
server13 server14 server15
server16 server17 server18
HEADER 2:
```

I need to merge everything between the two headers so the updated output file looks like this:

```
HEADER 1:
server1 server2 server3 server4 server5 server6 server7 server8 server9
HEADER 2:

HEADER 1:
server10 server11 server12 server13 server14 server15 server16 server17 server18
HEADER 2:
```

The header names always remain constant.

I'm using UnxUtils in Windows, so unfortunately I don't have awk to do the manipulation. How do I go about it using sed?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed '/HEADER 1/{n;:l N;/HEADER 2/b; s/\n//; bl}' input
```

- `n` skips/prints the current line (HEADER 1), clears buffer
- `l` is a label for looping (goto label)
- `N` adds (appends) lines to buffer (preserving newlines)
- `/HEADER 2/b`, where b is branch (without the label, it is break), break out when HEADER2 is seen
- `s/\n//` removes the newlines in the buffer
- `bl` jumps back to label `l`

Comment: Care to explain?

Comment: @DanMan, added some explanation

Comment: When I try this I get "unexpected EOF (pending }'s)

Answer (score 5):

This shows how it could be done using `awk`
You can download `Gawk` for Windows

```
awk '/HEADER/ {printf "\n%s\n",$0;next} {printf "%s ",$0}' file

HEADER 1:
server1 server2 server3 server4 server5 server6 server7 server8 server9
HEADER 2:

HEADER 1:
server10 server11 server12 server13 server14 server15 server16 server17 server18
HEADER 2:
```

Comment: `I'm using UnxUtils in Windows, so unfortunately I don't have awk`

Comment: This works perfectly too, thanks for your help and for the tip re Gawk for Windows