# How to merge lines between two patterns of square brackets

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want to merge lines between matching square bracket lines,and add comma like below

```
[1] 13:58:13 [FAILURE], webhost1 ,Exited with error code 255
[2] 13:58:14 [SUCCESS], webhost2
cmd1:
Friday October 4 2019 3:12:07 PM
cmd2:
vmw6222......
.........................
[3] 13:58:14 [SUCCESS], webhost3
cmd1:
Friday October 4 2019 3:12:07 PM
cmd2:
vmw6222.........
...........
[30] 15:12:08 [SUCCESS] vmw6211
cmd1:
Friday October 4 2019 3:12:08 PM
[31] 13:58:14 [SUCCESS], webhost4
Stderr: hostn : The term 'hostn' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, ^M
............................

Expected output
[1] 13:58:13 [FAILURE], webhost1 ,Exited with error code 255
[2] 13:58:14 [SUCCESS], webhost2, cmd1: Friday October 4 2019 3:12:07 PM, cmd2: vmw6222.....
[3] 13:58:14 [SUCCESS], webhost3, cmd1: Friday October 4 2019 3:12:07 PM, cmd2: vmw6222.........
[30] 15:12:08 [SUCCESS] vmw6211, cmd1: Friday October 4 2019 3:12:08 PM
[31] 13:58:14 [SUCCESS], webhost4, Stderr: hostn : The term 'hostn' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, ^M
```

I tried [Merge lines between two patterns using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094997/merge-lines-between-two-patterns-using-sed)
Tried below , but didn't helping me
can anyone help me where i wrong in below awk command

```
awk 'BEGIN {accum_line = "";} /^\[[0-9]+]/{if(length(accum_line)){print accum_line; accum_line = "";}} {accum_line = accum_line " ," $0;} END {if(length(accum_line)){print accum_line; }}'
```

Comment: Get rid of any `...`s from your sample input/output that aren't **really** part of your data as they just clutter the post make it less clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{printf("%s%s",$0~/^\[/ && FNR>1?ORS:FNR==1?"":OFS,$0)} END{print ""}'  Input_file
```

---

---

***Explanation:***

```
awk '                                                      ##Starting awk program here.
{
  printf("%s%s",$0~/^\[/ && FNR>1?ORS:FNR==1?"":OFS,$0)    ##Using printf to print lines with conditions, explained later in thread.
}
END{                                                       ##Mentioning END section of this awk program here.
  print ""                                                 ##Printing NULL value to print a new line here.
}
'  Input_file                                              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

***Explanation of `(%s%s",$0~/^\[/ && FNR>1?ORS:FNR==1?"":OFS,$0)` :***

```
%s%s --> means asking printf to print 2 strings.
on printing 1st string checking condition:
$0~/^\[/ && FNR>1?ORS:FNR==1?"" which means check if a line is starting from [ and NOT 1st line then print ORS(new line) or if a line is 1st line print NULL else print space in each line.
For 2nd string mentioned in printf simply mentioning $0 to print current line.
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `...`s from your input should appear in your output:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", (/^\[[0-9]+]/ ? ors : ","), $0; ors=ORS} END{print ""}' file
[1] 13:58:13 [FAILURE], webhost1 ,Exited with error code 255
[2] 13:58:14 [SUCCESS], webhost2,cmd1:,Friday October 4 2019 3:12:07 PM,cmd2:,vmw6222......,.........................
[3] 13:58:14 [SUCCESS], webhost3,cmd1:,Friday October 4 2019 3:12:07 PM,cmd2:,vmw6222.........,...........
[30] 15:12:08 [SUCCESS] vmw6211,cmd1:,Friday October 4 2019 3:12:08 PM
[31] 13:58:14 [SUCCESS], webhost4,Stderr: hostn : The term 'hostn' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, ^M,............................
```

Comment: Thanks helps me, but printing extra comma after cmd1:, & cmd2:,

Comment: How should the script know where to add a comma if not in place of **every** newline?

Comment: just to add comma before cmd1 and cmd2 and merge

Comment: I know WHAT you want but yo write software to do something you need to know WHY it's to be done. Is it based on the literal strings `cmd1` and `cmd2` or based on strings coming at a certain position in the block of lines or based on single-word-lines or lines ending with `:` or something else?

Comment: ALso see [my earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58237760/how-to-merge-lines-between-two-patterns-of-square-brackets/58238122?noredirect=1#comment102848458_58237760) because having those `...`s in your example is making your expected output not match the real output and so we can't simply compare expected to actual output to see if the script worked or not.