# Bash merge two specific lines into one

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed

I have a file that consists of two repeatedly occurring lines.

```
line1
     line2
line1
     line2
line1
     line2
```

I want to merge them so that the output file would look like:

```
line1 line2
line1 line2
line1 line2
```

Unfortunately I didn't succeed. 
In notepad++ I could do something like:

```
search: (line1)(\r\n)
replace: \1
```

Here I wanted to do the same but this:

```
sed -E 's/(line1)(\n)/\1/' my_file
```

doesn't work

Comment: You'll need the `N` command in sed to do this: `sed '{N;s/line1\n/line1/;}` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852132/sed-join-lines-together

Comment: Probably `sed -Ez 's/(line1)\r?\n/\1/' my_file` will work for you (with GNU sed)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: Or `sed 'N;s/line1[[:space:]]*/line1 /' my_file` to remove extra leading spaces from line2 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `paste` and `tr` for this:

```
cat file | paste -d" " - - | tr -s ' '

line1 line2
line1 line2
line1 line2
```

Comment: This one merged only first two lines. The rest remained unchanged. Nevertheless thank you.

Comment: How do you mean? It will go through the whole file and print alternate lines on one line. You could use `paste -d" " - - -` will print every 3 lines onto one and so forth.

Comment: Ok than it works. Is there any way to not specify dashes? Can't it go to the end of the file itself?

Comment: No, that's part of the command `- -` is 2 lines `- - -` is 3 lines `- - - -` is 4 lines etc.

Comment: Oh now I understand. It was working the whole time what I forgot to mention was that I had empty lines in between and hence I thought it was broken. Now I think that I like your answer the most.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` doesn't match across the line. You may use `perl` in slurp mode:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(line1)\R+\h+/$1 /g' file
```

```
line1 line2
line1 line2
line1 line2
line1 line2
```

Comment: Awesome this is exactly what I wanted. Doesn't sed really have any flag or something to match the whole line?

Comment: There are four spaces between line1 and line2

Comment: @Z.Szymon: Using sed you can do: `sed -E 'N;s/(line1)\n/\1/;' file`

Comment: @anubhava it has taken care of only the first two lines, the rest remained unchanged

Comment: Strangely on my sed or perl, it is changing full file.

Comment: It was working the whole time what I forgot to mention was that I had empty lines in between and hence I thought it was broken. I'm sorry.

Comment: @AlfredE.Noobman: Thanks, I overlooked space removal requirement in question, It is fixed now.

Comment: @Z.SzymonL Then you may need `perl -0777 -pe 's/(line1)R+\h+/$1 /g' file`