# Join or merge lines between two patterns inclusive (sed or awk)

Tags: awk, sed, merge, ksh

I have a large file with multi line SQL statements that I need to "join" into one liners. Consider the following:

```
create unique index <bla1 bla1>
    <more bla1 bla1>;
alter table <bla2 bla2>
    <more bla2 bla2>;
create index <bla3 bla3>
    <more bla3 bla3>;
alter table <bla4 bla4>
    <more bla4 bla4>
    <some more bla4 bla4>;
```

in which pattern1 would be "alter table" and pattern2 ";". I would like the output to be:

```
create unique index <bla1 bla1>
    <more bla1 bla1>;
alter table <bla2 bla2> <more bla2 bla2>;
create index <bla3 bla3>
    <more bla3 bla3>;
alter table <bla4 bla4> <more bla4 bla4> <some more bla4 bla4>;
```

I've seen other posts about merging lines with sed or awk (closest being [sed join lines together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852132/sed-join-lines-together), and [How to print lines between two patterns, inclusive or exclusive (in sed, AWK or Perl)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-print-lines-between-two-patterns-inclusive-or-exclusive-in-sed-awk-or) kinda gave me a couple of ideas), but they can't quite accomplish the task.
While I prefer the answer in sed or awk, any others will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does that first linked approach fail? And are those leading tabs or spaces?

Comment: How does that first linked approach fail?
- it joins when the last field is "0". I can extrapolate to say last character is ";" but that would join the "create index" too, which I don't want.
And are those leading tabs or spaces?
- They are spaces.

Comment: I don't have a good version of sed handy (long story), but try this: `sed ':a;/^alter table/{/;$/!{N;s/\n   //;ba}}'`

Comment: @Beta - It works great! I need to handle some unsightly extra spaces, but it works as desired! Add your suggestion as an answer so I can select it as the accepted answer.Also, a quick explanation would be appreciated... thanks!!!

Comment: Extra spaces. [facepalm] Let me try again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed ':a;/^alter table.*[^;].$/{N;s/\n //;ba}'
```

**EDIT:** That's what comes of not having the real tool to experiment with. All right, back to this one:

```
sed ':a;/^alter table/{/;$/!{N;s/\n //;ba}}'
```

Comment: actually the response you posted in the comments above worked great. this one, not so much... ^_^